# how to place an image in svg path as wall tiles

Tags: angularjs, svg

hi i have svg path where i am placing an image https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPksR.jpg  from . when i place its just display in center of path and not filling others area as following my desired image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNkJD.jpg

how i can place image on wall as tiles ?

```
<defs>
  <pattern  id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="stile.jpg"  width="100" height="100" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
 <path d="M 752 180 v 192 h 215 V 145 L 752 180 Z M 916 358 l -130 0.246 v -78.369 L 916 270 V 358 Z"/>
</path>



 <script>
jQuery(function($){
    $('path').click(function(){


       this.style.fill = "url(#img1)";
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
</script>
```

when i click on path with jquery am applying image on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your image has white borders. If you want to use that image you need to put the image inside a symbol with a viewBox that is cropping the white border of the image like so:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
<symbol id="s" viewBox="2.5 2.5 38 35">
<image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/NFhr6hq.jpg"  width="48" height="45" />
</symbol>
  <pattern  id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="30" height="30">
   <use xlink:href="#s" width="30" height="30" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>
```

Alternatively you may *use a different image* with no white borders and in this case you may use the @Alexandr_TT's solution.

#### UPDATE:

The OP is commenting:

> i have updatted question, there i have no rect but path . when i click on path , jquery update path fill area with image

In this case instead of filling the rect you fill the path like so:

```html
<svg viewBox="750 145 230 230" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
<symbol id="s" viewBox="3.1 2.5 38 35">
<image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/NFhr6hq.jpg"  width="48" height="45" />
</symbol>
  <pattern  id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="38" height="35">
   <use xlink:href="#s" width="38" height="35" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
<!--<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#img1)" />-->
<path d="M 752 180 v 192 h 215 V 145 L 752 180 Z M 916 358 l -130 0.246 v -78.369 L 916 270 V 358 Z" fill="url(#img1)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: i have updatted question, there i have no rect but path . when i click on path , jquery update path fill area with image

Comment: In this case you fill the path. I've updated my answer to show how. Please take a look

Comment: They are using canvas for this but SVG is a good alternative.

Comment: can you please suggest me what i need to use to create similar app like this ?

Comment: but they are using svg because canvas do not support click and other events

Comment: your solution work better for me but still have some issues. do i need  t height and width of image specific to <pattern> height width ? or any image will work for me ?

Comment: Depending on what you have you may use a different size or not. Please update your question and add the fragment of code you are talking about.

Comment: if i have other picture with width 90 and height 87 will its work same like this ? this example picture have width 48 and height 45

Comment: Your image may have or may have not the white empty rim. If it doesn't you can use the image inside the pattern. You may need to change the size of the image and also the size of the pattern

Comment: @enxanetta i have marked your answer thanks for your help. i need 1 more help if your can

Answer (score 1):

Pattern filling any shape

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#img1)" />
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <pattern  id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/NFhr6hq.jpg"  width="100px" height="100px" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#img1)" /> 

</svg>
```

Update

Tile Fill Path

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <pattern  id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="25" height="25">
    <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/NFhr6hq.jpg"  width="25px" height="25px" />
  </pattern>
</defs>

 <path stroke="gray" fill="url(#img1)" transform="translate(-700 -100)" d="M 752 180 v 192 h 215 V 145 L 752 180 Z M 916 358 l -130 0.246 v -78.369 L 916 270 V 358 Z" />

</svg>
```

Comment: but i have <path> where i am filling image via pattern

Comment: @Rahul king Add the path code to your question and I will refine my answer

Comment: i have updatted my code. am clicking on path and applying image on it with jquery

Comment: if i have multiple paths do i need to change transform value for all ?

Comment: @Rahul king Add a pattern to each path as in my example

Comment: @Rahul king As I understand from your additional conditions, the question becomes  completely different in content compared to the initial conditions. You have already been answered on the initial question. Therefore, you must select and accept the existing answer and ask a new question in another topic with all the new conditions.

Comment: but when i put transform attribute i do not get my desired result, my path just got rotated on other place. am asking do i need different transform values for each path ?

Comment: @Rahul king The example you gave works. If your other example does not work, then you need to change the attributes transform = "translate (X, Y)"

Comment: how i can get values of X and Y ? or do i need to use just x and y in translate ?

Comment: [translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)

Comment: thanks for your help but am not getting result with your solution  what i need